# build.properties - Valid entries in a Tycho build

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho, eclipse-pde

When I create Eclipse plug-in project, and after that try to build it with Maven/Tycho, one of the generated files is build.properties file. It contains several entries which describe what part of the project to be built.

My question is, what are the valid entries for build.properties file in a Tycho build? Is there any official documentation where I can see all valid entries for it?

Answer (score 5):

Since Tycho 0.21.0, there is a documentation page which lists [all build.properties entries supported by Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/BuildProperties.html). It also points to alternatives for non-supported entries.

Answer (score 0):

See

```
Plug-in Development Environment Guide > Reference > Build Configuration
Feature and Plug-in Build Configuration Properties
```

in your eclipse help documentation.